# Problem 3.28 from Folland’ Real Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

The problem is

> If $F\in NBV$, let $G(x)=\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert((-\infty,x])$. Prove that $\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert=\mu_{T_{F}}$ by showing that $G=T_{F}$ via the following steps.
>
> a. From the definition of $T_{F},\ T_{F}\leq G$.
>
> b. $\lvert\mu_{F}(E)\rvert\leq\mu_{T_{F}}(E)$ when $E$ is an interval, and hence when $E$ is a Borel set.
>
> c. $\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert\leq\mu_{T_{F}}$, and hence $G\leq T_{F}$.

Below are my attempts.

For a, fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then$$\begin{aligned}
T_{F}(x)&=\sup\left\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert F(x_{j})-F(x_{j-1})\rvert:n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty<x_{0}<...<x_{n}=x\right\rbrace \\
&=\sup\left\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert\mu_{F}((x_{j-1},x_{j}]):n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty<x_{0}<...<x_{n}=x\right\rbrace \\
&\leq\sup\left\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert((x_{j-1},x_{j}]):n\in\mathbb{N},-\infty<x_{0}<...<x_{n}=x\right\rbrace \\
&=\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert((x_{0},x])\leq\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert((-\infty,x])=G(x).\\
\end{aligned}$$
Hence $T_{F}\leq G$.

For b, assume $E=(a,b]$, where $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Choose $a=x_{0}<...<x_{n}=b$, then$$\begin{aligned}
\lvert\mu_{F}(E)\rvert&=\lvert F(b)-F(a)\rvert\\
&=\lvert F(b)-F(x_{n-1})+...+F(x_{1})-F(a)\rvert\\
&\leq\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert F(x_{j})-F(x_{j-1})\rvert\\
&\leq\mu_{T_{F}}((a,b]).\\
\end{aligned}$$

For c, if $E$ is a Borel set, use Exercise 3.21 we have$$\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert(E)=\sup\left\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert\mu_{F}(E_{j})\rvert:n\in\mathbb{N},\ E_{1},...,E_{n}\ \text{disjoint},\ E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}E_{j}\right\rbrace .$$Then from b,$$\lvert\mu_{F}\rvert(E)\leq\sup\left\lbrace \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu_{T_{F}}(E_{j}):n\in\mathbb{N},\ E_{1},...,E_{n}\ \text{disjoint},\ E=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}E_{j}\right\rbrace=\mu_{T_{F}}(E).$$

Does these work? Or are there a better proof for this problem? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why "hence when $E$ is a Borel set" in b. is true?

Comment: @sam2018 I think it’s because the family of Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by intervals.